# Mysql: search in combined columns

Tags: php, mysql, database, merge

I want to search a full name in my database.

But in my mysql db I have made the columns as following:

- first name
- inserts
- last name

How can i merge these columns in mysql that i can search on a full name?
probably with the %LIKE% attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to put the columns together

```
select * from your_table
where concat(first_name, ' ', inserts, ' ', last_name) like '%search_string%'
```